# Connection from App Maker to Cloud SQL is locked

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

Cloud SQL is locked, it tells me to contact Admin to unlock.

[image: Cloud SQL is locked, it tells me to contact Admin to unlock]

I've created Cloud SQL instance with service account "appmaker-maestro@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" on IAM & ADMIN. But App Maker doesn't see it. Added some tables by dbForge - it didn't helped.

I already created connection before in another app, some month ago and it worked. But now it doesn't see SQL.

Answer (score 5):

In order to configure Default Cloud SQL instance for App Maker you need to navigate to [admin.google.com](https://admin.google.com)`-> Apps -> Additional Google Services -> App Maker` and setup database there. Here is a link to more detailed instructions: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053

[image: Config default SQL]

You can also configure different CSQL instances for different departments within your organization.

Comment: Thank you it works now! One little thing. Here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#create-a-new-google-cloud-sql-database-for-your-app is wroten that at IAM&ADMIN i have to assign "SQL Client" Role for service account. But also it requeres SQL Admin Role. And than it works.

Comment: As per [cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app), you need to enable "Cloud SQL Administration API" and assign "Cloud SQL Client" role to the service account for connecting to Cloud SQL from the external App. Does it precisely ask for "Cloud SQL Admin" role?

Comment: Yes for Default Cloud SQL instance, because App Maker needs admin privileges to create/delete databases and users for apps. However admin permissions are not required for personal/custom instances.