# Can't access to Google AppMaker template

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I understand that Google Drive Table had been removed and AppMaker is using Cloud SQL nowadays. Then how can we access the template for eg this [one](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/)? I have access to Cloud SQL but the account is not mine but belongs to the organization.

[image: screenshot error]

How to configure the SQL connection to the Cloud SQL in the script while I can't access the template? Need help, Thanks!

Comment: You need to ask your domain admin to configure Default Cloud SQL. Here is a relevant discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763535/

Comment: why I can't find the setting for AppMaker in the Admin Console?

Comment: Where do you look for it? Do you have sufficient permissions?

Comment: Ok, get it so only admin can access the page and configure the Cloud SQL. They will create a new instance and setup the database. But can my AppMaker link with Cloud SQL instance created by another account? From this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osxqbNa-THk I understand that the Cloud SQL instance is created under same account to access the AppMaker.

Comment: what do you mean under `account`?

Comment: bcuz I dont have admin access, can I access the Cloud SQL?

Comment: By design only domain admins should be able to access configure Default Cloud SQL instance itself and if it is configured properly everybody across organization should be able to create App Maker apps with CSQL data backend. In other words `create/edit app` != `have access to CSQL`

Comment: the google-admin has grant create/edit but it is not accessible to other people in the organization except for the one with google-admin access, please advise

Comment: If you are sure that everything is configured correctly, feel free to file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410