# database settings Google Appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

Google's App Maker Setup Instruction seem to be inaccurate!
I am closely following the instructions found on https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql

For: Create a custom Google Cloud SQL database for your app/
Second Generation

[Step 6a is not valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkZZW.png)

[There is No Database Found in the Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Bs2.png)

Note I have followed all of the previous steps without issue.

Does anyone know what I can do to follow those intructions listed on the url above if Step 6a appears to be incorrect?

Note: This is my first ever post on stackoverflow, please be kind to my ignorance if obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: I too am stuck at this step - it appears there is something missing in the documentation. I wonder if it is something to do with me using an Edu account..?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to set it up:
[Connection from App Maker to Cloud SQL is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763535/connection-from-app-maker-to-cloud-sql-is-locked)

Basically, you need to assign the default instance within the Admin Console.

- Mike

Comment: Very good, I have followed those instructions. Nothing has changed yet but maybe I will need to wait 24 hours? It's been about 15 minutes so far. I will wait. Unless you know something else. It's interesting that when I added the instance name within Google Admin/Apps/Appmaker/Database settings it doesn't verify or visually tell me that it worked, saved, etc.

Comment: It worked very quickly for me - definitely within 5 minutes. Maybe you had not fully saved, perhaps?

Comment: Is the project you are using assigned to any organization unit? The SQL database has to be in a project that is under some organization unit.