# Linking Google AppMaker to CloudSQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

First time trying to link an App Maker project to my CloudSQL instance, however, I can't get past this message:

> The default Google Cloud SQL instance is not setup properly. Please ask a G Suite administrator to check the Google Cloud SQL configuration for your domain. (Reason: App Maker is unable to verify the default Google Cloud SQL instance. The instance must be a 2nd generation SQL database that is located in the us-central1 region.)

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the instructions presented here - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql#custom? I would put additional emphasis on step 4 for either 1st or 2nd gen instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up in the google domain admin console

admin.google.com-> Apps -> Additional Google Services -> App Maker

See: [Connection from App Maker to Cloud SQL is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763535/connection-from-app-maker-to-cloud-sql-is-locked)